# Getting Attendees from TaskRelation and populate Names in a text field from Tigger.isBefore , Trigger.isUpdate

Tags: apex, taskrelation

My first question here. I am having an issue with a trigger that I have spent hours trying to figure out. I would really appreciate some help to fix this issue which would help me to learn Triggers order of execution.

I have a class that's called from a master trigger Trigger.isBefore and Trigger.isUpdate. When a user saves a record, this class is getting a list of attendees IDs and populating a custom field "AttendeesCust__c". Issue is that I don't see the change until I save the record again and then it would show previously saved value.

Here is my class:

```
public class TaskAttAfterInsert {
    public void updateCustomTaskAttField(List<Task> tskLst)
    {
        List<Task> getTsk = new List<Task>();
        set<ID> whoIDs = new set<ID>();
        string sAttendees;
        List<Contact> conNames = new List<Contact>();
        if(trigger.isUpdate)
        { 
            Id getTskId=tskLst[0].Id;
            List<TaskRelation> tskAttendees = [SELECT Id, RelationId, TaskId, IsWhat, AccountId FROM TaskRelation Where TaskId= :getTskID AND isWhat != True];
            System.debug('List of Attendees: '+tskAttendees + 'List size is: '+tskAttendees.size()); //have to check for null
            Id relID0 = tskAttendees[0].RelationId;
            Integer sizeofAtt = tskAttendees.size();
        for(TaskRelation tr : tskAttendees)
            {
                List<Contact> conList = [Select Id, Name from Contact Where ID= :tr.RelationId]; 
                whoIDs.add(tr.RelationId);
                
                conNames = [select Id, Name from contact where Id IN : whoIDs];
                sAttendees = sAttendees + ',' + conNames[0].Name;                           
            }
                sAttendees = conNames[0].Name; // for testing to see saved record with two attendees
                sAttendees = sAttendees + conNames[1].Name; // for testing to see saved record with two attendees
            
        for(Task t : tskLst) //Updating Task coming from Trigger
            {
                t.cibcus_AttendeesCust__c = sAttendees;      
             }
            
           
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Trigger is beforeUpdate on Task? -- why is the class named TaskAttAfterInsert?

Comment: Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Your are correct, I need to change the class name to TaskAttBeforeInsert but this would not resolve my issue. I am calling this class from master trigger isBefore and isUpdate.